# SQL Server 2008 R2 service packs

Tags: sql-server, update

Are the SQL Server service packs 'cumulative' or 'incremental'?

The scenario is that we have a couple of instances running on SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM and we have been asked to patch it up to SP3 level. I'm not sure if I just apply SP3 or do I need to do SP1 - SP2 - SP3

Comment: SP's and CU's are cumulative. Go ahead apply SP3 it would include all fixes for SP1 and SP2.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 service packs are cumulative and can be used to upgrade all releases of SQL Server 2008 R2 to Service Pack 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> SQL Server 2008 R2 service packs are cumulative and can be used to
>   upgrade all releases of SQL Server 2008 R2 to Service Pack 3.

From http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=44271

Given the documentation, you should be able to go directly from SP0 to SP3.